# Error while invoking Internet Explorer browser using Selenium

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

Can anyone please help with the Selenium code below. I am getting an error while invoking Internet Explorer for automation testing.

Code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\microsoftwebdriver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

  }
```

}

Error screenshot attached:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### InternetExplorerDriver

[InternetExplorerDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver.html) class is the [WebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) implementation that controls the *IEServerDriver* and  and allows you to drive *Internet Explorer* browser running on the local machine. This class is provided as a convenience for easily testing the InternetExplorer browser. The control server which each instance communicates with will live and die with the instance.

To create a new instance of the *IEServerDriver* you need to use the **IEServerDriver** binary instead of *MicrosoftWebDriver.exe* which you need to download from [selenium-release.storage](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html), unzip and provide the *absolute path* within the `System.setProperty()` line. So your effective code block will be:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\path\\to\\IEServerDriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The code is working now without error.